# Is there a female or gender neutral equivalent for the verb to sire?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, gender-neutral, feminine

Is there a good equivalent for *to sire* I could use for a woman who mothered a child? Obviously other than *to mother* itself.

Comment: Any specific connotation or context? Sire is normally used of racehorses. Are we talking genetic material, childbirth, acting as a parent, performing child-raising, or some combination?

Comment: I don't think you're using the "synonyms" tag correctly. The "single-word-request" tag may work better. It asks for a sample sentence, which would help to resolve @StuartF 's questions.

Comment: The question is entirely clear. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sire "sire" => to become the male parent of an animal or the father of a child. Nevertheless, I cannot think of or find a female equivalent. Even "to beget" (which I thought might be useful) seems to be regarded as a purely male function in dictionaries. So I cannot answer. Anyone else?

Answer (score 5):

"[Conceive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceive)" and "[bear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bear)" (def 3) are pretty close, biologically speaking.
"[Beget](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/beget)" could be used for either gender, but is commonly a synonym for "sire."

Comment: Conceiving does not necessarily mean you become a mother. Beget is a male function according to Cambridge "to be the father of". So "bear" is probably the best. The man sires, the woman bears, although the two actions are not contemporaneous so are not entirely equivalent.

Comment: I do think that as we are referring to the results of sexual intercourse between men and women, the word "sex" should be used, not "gender". (Not just because I am a biological scientist.)

Answer (score 5):

The poster said it:

**[mother](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mother)**

Merriam-Webster has the first definition as a verb:

> 1 a: to give birth to
>    b: to give rise to : PRODUCE

The perhaps more common usage as “to care for or protect like a mother” is the second.

The OED has it as “chiefly figurative”, dating from the 15th century, but gives a literal example from the *Scientific American* of 1986:

> Through normal birth she has just mothered a normal, contented baby.

**Postscript**

I see now that the poster didn’t want *mother*. Too bad — that’s the answer. He could also try *spawn* as a sex-neuter term, but not if he didn’t wish to get into a fight.

Answer (score 2):

The commonest verb, an extension of the meaning "to carry", is "**to bear**":

OED:

> **1 b.** transitive. **Of a woman or other female mammal: to carry (offspring) (in the womb); to be pregnant with.** Also intransitive.
>
> 1709   I. Littlebury tr. Herodotus Hist. II. vi. 108   *Women are not always accustom'd to bear their Children ten Months.*
>
> 2019   Emory Wheel (Emory Univ., Atlanta) (Nexis) 24 Apr. 1   *Bearing a child she does not want to keep and in need of a place to stay, Deb pleads for Ollie's help.*

And from [Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/):

> "She bore him five children, including Francis." The Guardian
>
> "He sired nine children (including one with Ms. Ullmann)." The New
> York Times

Comment: "She bore him five children" is a benefactive usage.

Comment: Only by dint of the "him", which can be omitted.

Comment: But this is, importantly, a DOC (as with a ditransitive usage: 'She gave him a pair of socks') whereas 'transitive' (as with all the other examples) is usually considered to mean 'having a direct object' (no mention of a second object).

Answer (score -3):

If you are referring to (a) the birth and upbringing of animals or (b) the upbringing of people, one option would be to use the gender-neutral terms *[rear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rear)* or *[raise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raise)*. Both definitions are from Merriam-Webster:

> rear, verb [...]
>
> 3a(1) : to breed and raise (an animal) for use or market
>
> (2) : to bring to maturity or self-sufficiency usually through nurturing care
>
> > reared five children // birds rearing their young

> raise, verb, [...]
>
> 5a : grow, cultivate
>
> > raise cotton
>
> b : to bring to maturity : rear
>
> > raise a child
>
> c : to breed and bring (an animal) to maturity

For animals the verbs refer to the entire process of conception and upbringing. For people, it usually refers to what happens after birth: the parenting (fathering or mothering) that brings a wee one through the stages of childhood. The usage can be seen in stock phrases like *born and raised* ([The Fresh Prince of Bel Aire](https://genius.com/Dj-jazzy-jeff-and-the-fresh-prince-the-fresh-prince-of-bel-air-lyrics): "In West Philadelphia born and raised") and familial descriptions (in an April 14, 2002 book review by Yilu Zhao in the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2002/04/14/education/books-dr-spock-where-are-you.html): "a Sichuan province mother, Weihua Liu, tells how she reared her daughter to be Harvard material").

I grew up with *raise up* in my Southern American dialect, which the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/157611) (11d) notes as a variant. "She raised him up right" is an informal turn of phrase I've heard several times.

Comment: **Raise** and **rear** seem both to occur after birth/the fertilisation of the ovum as is implied in "to sire". You can raise and read other people's children but only "sire" your own.

Comment: Yes, that is as I noted. That sense is, however, a synonym of "to mother" or the OED-noted extended use of "to sire": "1902   O. Wister Virginian xiv. 160   The blamed thing was sired by a whole doggone Dutch syndicate."